# passing InputStream as parameter to web service

Tags: java, file-upload, jersey

I am trying to upload file but i am not doing it through html form. QueryParam and PathParam can't be used. So can anyone tell how to pass stream.

My HttPClient looks like:

```
try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        InputStream stream=new FileInputStream(new File("C:/localstore/ankita/Desert.jpg"));
        String url="http://localhost:8080/Cloud/webresources/fileupload";
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
```

and my web service class looks somewhat like:

```
@Path("/fileupload")
public class UploadFileService {

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)

public Response uploadFile(InputStream in) throws IOException
{     
    String uploadedFileLocation = "c://filestore/Desert.jpg" ;

    // save it
    saveToFile(in, uploadedFileLocation);

    String output = "File uploaded via Jersey based RESTFul Webservice to: " + uploadedFileLocation;

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

}

// save uploaded file to new location
private void saveToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,String uploadedFileLocation) 
{
    try {
        OutputStream out = null;
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) 
        {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Can anyone help??

```
 String url="http://localhost:8080/Cloud/webresources/fileupload";
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(new File("C:/localstore/ankita/Desert.jpg")), -1);
        reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
        reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

How web service will look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it that way.  You can't pass a stream in an HTTP request, because streams are not serializable.

The way to do this is to is create an `HttpEntity` to wrap the stream (e.g. an `InputStreamEntity`) then attach it to the `HttpPOST` object using `setEntity`.  Then the POST is sent, the client will read from your stream and send the bytes as the request's "POST data".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try to do this way. Will tell you if it works.

Comment: I got following thing but how web service will call this? Added code above at the end.